# Why do Euler angles suffer from gimbal lock but not rotation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

I know why Euler angles suffer from gimbal lock (with the help of a physical gimbal/gyro model), but I read from various sources ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Alternate_orientation_representation),[2](https://base.movella.com/s/article/Understanding-Gimbal-Lock-and-how-to-prevent-it?language=en_US)) that rotation matrices do not. Aren't rotation matrices constructed from Euler angles? What makes them immune?

(As a bonus: what would you recommend as a comprehensive guide to understanding 3D rotations? I find this topic quite confusing, and the myriad of convention differences only makes it more so.)

Thank you.

Comment: Rotation matrices encode each axis of rotation independently so there is no ambiguity as to which is rotating. Euler angles are defined relative to each other, which allows for locking.

Comment: You **can** construct a rotation matrix using Euler angles, but you can do it in other ways instead. For example, every rotation in 3D has an axis and an angle of rotation around that axis, which completely describes the rotation, and you can convert that representation directly into a rotation matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Euler angles are defined relative to each other, as in the three rotations are sequenced one after another? If we specify extrinsic rotations for the three standard coordinate axis (xyz), would this eliminate the ambiguity problem?

Comment: Whenever you try and specify a rotation using three angles, all in the range $[0,2\pi)$, you run into a topological problem. Those three angles are all points on a circle $S^1$. So the space of the three angles is $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$. On the other hand, the space of rotation is (for example via quaternions) $S^3$, the 4D sphere. The mapping from the Euler angle space $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ to the rotation space $SO_3\simeq S^3$ is continuous and surjective. But the two spaces are not homeomorphic, and hence it cannot have a continuous inverse. Gimbal locks are a manifestation of that.

Comment: Yes, as @JyrkiLahtonen says, there is an intrinsic, inescapable (topological) reason for gimbal lock... and the same geometry explains why other systems avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Because rotation matricies are not really about rotation, but change of basis.... a very specific change of basis which preserves orthogonality, length and handedness (i.e. $SO(3)$).  In this very special case such a change of basis can be thought of as a rotation.  If we think about the 9 elements in a rotation matrix under the constraints of orthogonality, length preservation and handedness, there are really only 3 degrees of freedom.  These may be abstractly though of as a position on a sphere and an angle.  It is because any parameterization of the sphere always has two singularities (i.e. you loose one degree of freedom (e.g. the N and S pole for lat-long parameterization) ) that the phenomenon of gimbal lock happens.  It is a fundamental property of the underlying geometry.  If the sphere is parameterized with three parameters, this issue goes away (i.e. axis-angle, quaternions).

So the real questions is why doesn't gimbal lock occur with four parameters?  It is becuse the sphere can be parameterized with three parameters and not be subject to singularities.